# Inserting node at beginning of singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a problem with my `add_to_list` function here.

I'm using this function to add a node to the begging of the singly linked list that referenced by list pointer.

The problem is: **only** the first node is added, then if I add any more, I lose the trace of the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node *add_to_list(struct node *list , int n){
     struct node *new_node ;
     new_node = malloc( sizeof(struct node) ); //create new node
     if(new_node == NULL){
         printf("Error ,malloc failed to allocate memory\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     new_node->value = n; //initiate value field
     new_node->next = list;
     return new_node;
}

int main(){
    struct node * first = NULL;
    struct node * temp = first;
    first = add_to_list(first,10);
    if(first != NULL)
        printf("node added\n");
    else
        printf("add failed\n");
    first = add_to_list(first,20);
    if(first == NULL)
        printf("node added\n");
    else
        printf("add failed\n");
    first = add_to_list(first,30);
    if(first == NULL)
        printf("node added\n");
    else
        printf("add failed\n");

    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d-->",(temp->value));
        temp = temp ->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your tests for `first` being null or not are inverted (except the first one).

Comment: At the start of `main()`, you have `struct node * temp = first;` statement which assign `NULL` to `temp`. Since in `while` loop, you are printing the list so before `while` loop you should assign `first` to `temp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at the beginning of `main` you've got these two lines...

```
struct node * first = NULL;
struct node * temp = first;
```

...which assign `NULL` to `first` and then the value of `first` to `temp` which means both of them are `NULL`. This is a one time assignment - `temp` won't get updated as `first` changes.

When you get to the bottom of the function you have this loop, but nothing has updated the value of `temp` since it was first assigned `NULL`.

```
while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("%d-->",(temp->value));
    temp = temp ->next;
}
```

The solution is to assign the current value of `first` to `temp` just before the loop like so:

```
temp = first;
while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("%d-->",(temp->value));
    temp = temp ->next;
}
```